# Compare values in a matrix with a threshold and create a list of exceeding it

Tags: python, pandas

I need to compare values in a matrix with  a threshold and create a table with not only indexes but also with column name where a value exceeds the threshold.

Eg.

Original table:

[image]

need to create a list of **Id_Class** that exceed the threshold,
however I would like to have an intermediary binary matrix before to send them to the list.

like this

[image]

and the final list

[image]

I've tried the code to create a binary matrix but it doesn't work.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],
           'region':['a','b','c'],
           'threshold':[0.4, 0.5, 0.3],
           'class_1':[0.2, 0.3, 0.3],
           'class_2':[0.6, 0.2, 0.1],
           'class_3':[0.4, 0.6, 0.1]})

df1 = df.set_index(['id', 'region', 'threshold'])
df1=df1.where(df1 >=df['threshold'] , 1, 0).reset_index()
```

I will be grateful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare numpy arrays with broadcasting and boolean mask convert to integers:

```
df.iloc[:, 3:] = (df.iloc[:, 3:].values >= df['threshold'].values[:, None]).astype(int)
print (df)
   id region  threshold  class_1  class_2  class_3
0   1      a        0.4        0        1        1
1   2      b        0.5        0        0        1
2   3      c        0.3        1        0        0
```

Another solution:

```
arr = (df.iloc[:, 3:].values >= df['threshold'].values[:, None]).astype(int)
print (arr)
[[0 1 1]
 [0 0 1]
 [1 0 0]]

df = df.iloc[:, :3].join(pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=df.columns[3:], index=df.index))
print (df)
   id region  threshold  class_1  class_2  class_3
0   1      a        0.4        0        1        1
1   2      b        0.5        0        0        1
2   3      c        0.3        1        0        0
```

For column with `1` values use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape:

```
df2 = (df.set_index('id')
         .iloc[:, 2:]
         .stack()
         .rename_axis(('id','class'))
         .reset_index(name='a')
         .query('a == 1')
         .drop('a', 1))
print (df2)
   id    class
1   1  class_2
2   1  class_3
5   2  class_3
6   3  class_1
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael! When trying my code the error message was: "ValueError: For argument "inplace" expected type bool, received type int" and I realized it was something wrong with datatype.. I couldn't understand why 'threshold' couldn't be compared with 'classes' since they are of the same type...bu now, I do thanks to your code!

Comment: The second part of the code works great ... I need to spend some time to follow the python's logic, but I'm always happy to learn something new in python. Thank you!!

Comment: @Vero- how working `df.iloc[:, 3:] = (df.iloc[:, 3:].values >= df['threshold'].values[:, None])` ?

Comment: @Vero - added new solution.

Comment: thank you, cod works perfectly! I just have a question - I need to attach the third column to the list (with a value that exceeds the threshold). Is it possible to adjust it in the code or code should be rewrite?

Comment: I didn't know how it works, sorry:) I will do it for all my previous questions