# Pandas combine VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP or how to pick a value in a matrix

Tags: python, pandas

In my [previous task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56987731/compare-values-in-a-matrix-with-a-threshold-and-create-a-list-of-exceeding-it) I needed to create a list based on threshold and it was solved. I then needed to complete it with next steps but I thought it would be helpful to create a separate question.
Basically, I need to bring a value from a matrix to the DataFrame creating a new column:

I have a list from previous task:

[image]

and the matrix:

[image]

I need to pick a value corresponding to the value in a crossing cell of row and column.

[image]

What the easiest way to do so?
Thank you for any help

here are simple trial dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],
               'class':['class_1', 'class_5', 'class_3']})


matrix = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],
               'class_1':[9,5,7],
               'class_2':[8,4,6],
               'class_3':[7,3,8],
               'class_4':[5,6,6],
               'class_5':[0,8,9]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

@Erfan suggests:

```
df['new_col'] = matrix.set_index('id').lookup(df['id'], df['class'])
```

Which is better than my original statement below:

```
matrix = matrix.set_index('id')

df['new_col'] = matrix.lookup(df['id'], df['class'])

df
```

OUtput:

```
   id    class  new_col
0   1  class_1        9
1   2  class_5        8
2   3  class_3        8
```

Comment: No need for inplace set_index: `df['new_col'] = matrix.set_index('id').lookup(df['id'], df['class'])`

Comment: @Erfan True.  I aggree mind if i add to this solution?

Comment: Perfect in its simplicity! :) Thank you very much @Scott Boston